# A cleaner way for this case expression in sql

Tags: sql

I would really like to clean up this sql code, but not too sure of the best approach. Any advice would be most appreciated (it continues up to 20 times.)

I had thought maybe a loop, but not quite sure how to do this in sql, maybe I need to set up a function outside for this? Any recommendations would be most appreciated.

```
WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*1) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*2) THEN 2
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*2) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*3) THEN 3
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*3) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*4) THEN 4
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*4) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*5) THEN 5
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*5) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*6) THEN 6
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*6) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*7) THEN 7
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*7) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*8) THEN 8
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*8) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*9) THEN 9
    WHEN Date BETWEEN Sea.StartDate+(27*9) AND Sea.StartDate+(27*10) THEN 10 
END) AS Cycle,

    Convert(BIT, CASE 
            WHEN    Date = Sea.StartDate OR 
                    Date = Sea.StartDate+(28*1) OR 
                    Date = Sea.StartDate+(28*2) OR
                    Date = Sea.StartDate+(28*3) OR
                    Date = Sea.StartDate+(28*4) OR
                    Date = Sea.StartDate+(28*5) 
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS CStart
```

Comment: When asking for alternatives, it might be useful to specify the exact database system you are using. Not all databases can support the same SQL functionality and your database system might provide efficient SQL functionality that is not available in other systems.

Comment: @ranto1 . . . The question is quite confusing.  Why are you using 27 in the first expression but 28 for the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bart Hofland says, the specifics will vary per database.

In the spirit of "teach a man to fish...", for SQL server, the first part will be something like this:

```
select datediff(d, startDate, date)/27
```

That should help with your Cycle.  You can +/- up or down, but you get the gist I am sure.

The second one to calculate CStart is simply a fiddly condition.  There are *different* ways to achieve it, but I don't see any alternative that is any better.

Comment: Yes. And other database systems like Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL might provide the `EXTRACT` function to get the number of days between twose date values.

Comment: Thank you all. I'm actually ashamedly not a 100% sure what the database system is (weird situation and I'm more of a novice than a guru) I think it's Microsoft server but it's through a reporting platform. Thanks for your help